# Submitting spark jobs from VSCode to Azure Synapse stop working

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-synapse

Extension 'Spark & Hive Tools' to submit job from Visual Studio Code stop working for me and my colleagues from yesterday.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mshdinsight.azure-hdinsight&ssr=false#overview
it is very strange that it started to show on market only few installs.

From Visual Studio Code we used context meny to Synapse: PySpark batch and now dissaperead.
Any ideas? What was changed from MS side?

Comment: I am able to install the extension in VS code successfully check it from your end [image](https://i.imgur.com/K5BRe1a.png)

Comment: It is not main problem to install extension, currently it is 1.1.17 and I also could install it,  I am saying  that probably after updating from 1.1.16 to 1.1.17 supporting submit jobs from VSCode to Synapse Spark pool just has gone. And even I dont have option to roll back to previous one from VSCode.

Comment: like temporally workaround my team disabled auto update of extension in VSCode and roll back to 1.1.16 version using file 'mshdinsight.azure-hdinsight-1.1.16.vsix'